# How to call a varargs function via dbus?

Tags: c, dbus

How to call a varargs function via dbus, like printf?

The server is written in C, the client is written in Python.

My questions are how to write the XML spec file? And how to write my GObject?

Thanks in advance.

[I use DBus-GLib.]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no way to call a variadic function programmatically with varying number and type of arguments. You could use the corresponding "v" functions (`vprintf` etc.) but there's no way to make the `va_list` to pass to them from foreign code and pass it over DBus.

In any case you really need to rethink your design. It's unsafe to call `printf` with a format string that's not 100% controlled by your program. Passing a client-provided format string is a formula for disaster, because `printf` invokes **undefined behavior** if the format string does not match the arguments. In nearly all real-world situations, **this will mean privilege elevation vulns**!

Comment: I see.. But how to use the "v" functions?

Comment: When the args come from a foreign language or even another process across DBus, there is no way to use the "v" functions because you can't make the `va_list`. Calling `printf` the way you're trying to do is simply wrong. If the format string's types are known in advance, use a wrapper function that takes those exact types and validates that the format string matches them (this is no easy task in itself!). If the format string's types are not known in advance, and provided by an external program, then what you're doing is fundamentally unsafe.

Comment: By the way, why don't you just call the equivalent of `snprintf` from Python then pass the resulting string across DBus??